# Duplicate results in foreach data in the data table with Php in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a list of user, and a list of action he has performed. When I try to display the user is registered and the history data from both tables, I get duplicate results. I use my HistoryManagerController to get the information about the actions and the user who performed them, The code below works except I get duplicate results where the first result in the table matches 100%, the second result does not match, then continues with the same duplicate value for each user.
I know these are basic things that people need to do, so if anyone can point me in the right direction of what I need to learn to make this happen, it will help me throughout my project.

Thank you!

### HistoryController

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\ActionHistorique;
use App\Entity\Users;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Services\HistoriqueLogs;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;



class GestionHistoriqueController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var HistoriqueLogs
     */
    private $logHistorique;
    /**
     * @var ManagerRegistry
     */
    private $doctrine;

    public function __construct(
        HistoriqueLogs $logHistorique,
        ManagerRegistry $doctrine
    ) {
        $this->logHistorique = $logHistorique;
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/gestion/historique", name="app_gestion_historique")
     */
    public function dashboardAdmin(RequestStack $requestStack): Response
    {
    $params = $requestStack->getSession();
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $projet =  $params->get('projet');
    $modules = $params->get('modules');
    $fonctionnalites = $params->get('fonctionnalites');
    $adresseWeb = $this->getParameter('adresse_web');

    $actionHistoriques = $this->doctrine->getRepository(ActionHistorique::class)->findBy(['projetId' => $projet->getId()]);

     $projetNom = $projet->getProjet();

    $dataJson = array();

foreach ($actionHistoriques as  $actionHistorique) {

    $listUsers = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Users::class)->findAll();

 /* getter pour récuperer les nom et prenom des id associé aux utilisateurs dans le tableau.
 Et ensuite faire le reste dans le deuxième foreach et call le tableau pour le remplir */

    foreach ($listUsers as $user) {
        
    $nomUser = $user->getNom();
    $prenomUser = $user->getPrenom();

        // Injection des données dans le tableau 
        $mesDonnes = array(

            "nom"=> $nomUser,
            "prenom"=> $prenomUser,
            "projet"=> $projetNom,
            "date"=> $actionHistorique->getDate()->format('d/m/Y'),
            "actionEffectuée"=> $actionHistorique->getAction(),
            "CodeST/TI/PT/LT/BP/BA"=> $actionHistorique->getCode(),
            "nomCode"=> $actionHistorique->getNom(),
        );
        
        $dataJson[] = $mesDonnes;          
    }
}
            return $this->render('Historique/gestionHistorique.html.twig', [
                'user' => $user,
                'projet' => $projet,
                'modules' => $modules,
                'fonctionnalites'=> $fonctionnalites,
                'adresseWeb'=> $adresseWeb,
                'actionHistorique'=> json_encode($dataJson),
            ]);
        }
    }
```

### GestionHistory

```
 {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{encore_entry_link_tags('tabulator')}}

{% endblock %}
    {% block sudalysBody %}
    <section>
      <div id="singleTab" class="box box-info">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h2 class="box-title">Historique Easy Exploit</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="infos">
<div>
  <select id="filter-field">
    <option value="nom">Nom</option>
    <option value="prénom">Prénom</option>
    <option value="projet">Projet</option>
    <option value="actionEffectuée">Action effectuée</option>
    <option value="CodeST/TI/PT/LT/BP/BA">Code de l'objet</option>
    <option value="nomCode">Nom de l'objet</option>
  </select>

  <select id="filter-type">
    <option id="filter-type" value="like"></option>
  </select>

  <input id="filter-value" type="text" placeholder="Rechercher">

  <button id="filter-clear">Réintialiser</button>
</div>
          <div id="monTable"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
        
    {% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}

<script>
 var gestionHistorique = '{{actionHistorique | e('js') | raw}}';
gestionHistorique = JSON.parse(gestionHistorique);

// gestionHistorique.forEach( e => {
//   console.log(e);
  
// });
  $(document).ready(function() {

//custom max min header filter
var minMaxFilterEditor = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams){

    var end;

    var container = document.createElement("span");

    //create and style inputs
    var start = document.createElement("input");
    start.setAttribute("type", "date");
    start.setAttribute("placeholder", "Min");
    start.style.padding = "6px";
    start.style.width = "50%";
    start.style.boxSizing = "border-box";

    start.value = cell.getValue();

    function buildValues(){
        success({
            start:start.value,
            end:end.value,
        });
    }

    function keypress(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            buildValues();
        }

        if(e.keyCode == 27){
            cancel();
        }
    }

    end = start.cloneNode();
    end.setAttribute("placeholder", "Max");

    start.addEventListener("change", buildValues);
    start.addEventListener("blur", buildValues);
    start.addEventListener("keydown", keypress);

    end.addEventListener("change", buildValues);
    end.addEventListener("blur", buildValues);
    end.addEventListener("keydown", keypress);


    container.appendChild(start);
    container.appendChild(end);

    return container;
 }

//custom max min filter function

function 
minMaxFilterFunction(headerValue,rowValue,rowData,filterParams) {
//headerValue - the value of the header filter element
//rowValue - the value of the column in this row
//rowData - the data for the row being filtered
//filterParams - params object passed to the headerFilterFuncParams property
//convert strings into dates

    if (headerValue.start != "") {
        headerValue.start = new Date(headerValue.start);
    }

    if (headerValue.end != "") {
        headerValue.end = new Date(headerValue.end);
    }

    if(rowValue){
        const [day, month, year] = rowValue.split('/');
        const result = [year, month, day].join('-');
        var rowValue1 = new Date(result);

        if(headerValue.start != ""){
            if(headerValue.end != ""){
                if(rowValue1 >= headerValue.start && rowValue1 <= headerValue.end){
                        return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                if(rowValue1 >= headerValue.start){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }else{
            if(headerValue.end != ""){
                if(rowValue1 >= headerValue.end){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true; 
//must return a boolean, true if it passes the filter.
}
//Define variables for input elements
var fieldEl = document.getElementById("filter-field");
var typeEl = document.getElementById("filter-type");
var valueEl = document.getElementById("filter-value");

//Trigger setFilter function with correct parameters
function updateFilter(){
  var filterVal = fieldEl.options[fieldEl.selectedIndex].value;
  var typeVal = typeEl.options[typeEl.selectedIndex].value;

  var filter = filterVal == "function" ? customFilter : filterVal;

  if(filterVal == "function" ){
    typeEl.disabled = true;
    valueEl.disabled = true;
  }else{
    typeEl.disabled = false;
    valueEl.disabled = false;
  }

  if(filterVal){
    table.setFilter(filter,typeVal, valueEl.value);
  }
}

//Update filters on value change
document.getElementById("filter-field").addEventListener("change", updateFilter);
document.getElementById("filter-type").addEventListener("change", updateFilter);
document.getElementById("filter-value").addEventListener("keyup", updateFilter);

//Clear filters on "Clear Filters" button click
document.getElementById("filter-clear").addEventListener("click", function(){
  valueEl.value = "";

  table.clearFilter();
});
var table = new Tabulator("#monTable", {
     
          data: gestionHistorique,
          layout: "fitColumns",
          pagination: "local",
          paginationSize: 20,
          paginationSizeSelector: [20, 40, 60, 100],
          paginationCounter: "rows",
          paginationCounter: "rows",
    columns:[
        {title:"Nom", field:"nom",hozAlign:"center"},
        {title:"Prénom", field:"prenom",hozAlign:"center"},
        {title:"Projet", field:"projet",hozAlign:"center"},
        {title:"Date", field:"date", sorter:"datetime",hozAlign:"center",formatter:"datetime", formatterParams:{
                inputFormat:"dd/MM/yyyy",
                outputFormat:"dd/MM/yyyy",
                invalidPlaceholder:"(invalid date)",
            },  headerFilter:minMaxFilterEditor, headerFilterFunc:minMaxFilterFunction, headerFilterLiveFilter:false},
         {title:"Action effectuée",field:"actionEffectuée",hozAlign:"center"},
        {title:"Code Objet", field:"CodeST/TI/PT/LT/BP/BA",hozAlign:"center"},
        {title:"Nom Objet", field:"nomCode",hozAlign:"center"},
    ],
    });
});

</script>
  
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @DensetusCode, please add your Historique/gestionHistorique.html.twig so everyone could see how you iterate over your data.

Comment: I have added my Historique/gestionHistorique.html.twig thanks you ;)

Comment: I still don't see how you iterate over your data in twig. You pass `actionHistorique` to twig, but I don't see how you use it there

Comment: Are entities `User` and `ActionHistorique` somehow related to each other? Any `ManyToOne` and/or `OneToMany` between those two ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1** Try moving the code:

```
$listUsers = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Users::class)->findAll();
```

before the foreach:

```
...
$dataJson = array();

$listUsers = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Users::class)->findAll();

foreach ($actionHistoriques as  $actionHistorique) {

/* getter pour récuperer les nom et prenom des id associé aux utilisateurs dans le tableau.
   Et ensuite faire le reste dans le deuxième foreach et call le tableau pour le remplir */
...
```

I had encountered a similar problem when iterating over entityRepository find() call.

And if it doesn't solve your problem at least you will have better performances.

**EDIT:**

**2** It seems that in your code you don't check if the action you are iterating is being done by the user in the inner foreach. So for each action and each user you retrieved from the database you add an entry in the **$mesDonnes** array.

I suppose that the 2 tables are linked by a foreign key or other reference and the code should be more something like:

```
foreach ($actionHistoriques as $actionHistorique) {
   $user = $actionHistorique->getUser();
   $nomUser = $user->getNom();
   $prenomUser = $user->getPrenom();
   $mesDonnes = ....
           
   $dataJson[] = $mesDonnes;
}

//or
foreach ($actionHistoriques as $actionHistorique) {
   foreach ($listUsers as $user) {
       // madeThisAction() is a method that you should code specifically for your project
       if ($user->madeThisAction($actionHistorique)) {       
           $nomUser = $user->getNom();
           $prenomUser = $user->getPrenom();
           $mesDonnes = ....
           
           $dataJson[] = $mesDonnes;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but I still have the same problem :/

Comment: @DensetsuCode for **each** `$actionHistorique` you iterate over **all** users again and again... and put data to `$mesDonnes` I think that's the problem. I assume you want user-data **only** of specific (related) Users

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you want to output in your table, but as V-Light said, you are doing 2 foreach for actions and users but not checking if the action is linked to the user.

Comment: Hi, @Bl457Xor thank you for your feedback, in my table I want to display all the actions performed by the user, the changes, the connection, deletion and creation that it performs on the software is what I use my tables

Comment: @DensetsuCode How you retrieve your data depends on the relation between your Users Entity and the ActionHistorique Entity in Doctrine. You could provide the code of those entities, but I guess there should be a OneToMany relation (one user, many actions) and your ActionHistorique Entity should have a getUser() method to retrieve the linked user (if that the case my first example code should do the trick, if you handle all your sorting and filtering with Javascript (not advised for a large number of entry in your table, but could get you started)).